# How to create an arithmetic expression with lenght of items in each row of a column using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_ids_table (
  id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  price DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_ids_table 
    (id, price) 
VALUES 
    ('id_01, id_02', 100),
    ('id_03', 200),
    ('id_04', 300),
    ('id_05', 400),
    ('id_06, id_07, id_08', 500);
```

Output:

[image]

Now I'd like to reach this result below, where I split each separated value by comma, and then I calculate each price divided by the length of id items in each individual row, creating the **new_id** and **new_price** columns like this:

[image]

Is it possible in SQL? What would it be the simplest solution for a begginer student like me?
I have a SQL Fiddle created here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aaf730/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert delimiter separated string into row then using cte for getting desired result.

```
-- PostgreSQL(v11) (Based on image)
WITH cte as (select unnest(string_to_array(id, ', ')) new_id , id, price
FROM my_ids_table)
SELECT c.id, c.price, c.new_id, t.new_price :: decimal(10, 2)
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(price)/COUNT(id) new_price
            FROM cte
            GROUP BY id) t
        ON c.id = t.id;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a3d49af9342b55cfb780fa212ca1545f

Based on actual data set where **same delimited string** exists **multiple** times with **different** price. Use ORDER BY row_num if needed.

```
-- PostgreSQL(v11)
WITH cte as (
     SELECT unnest(string_to_array(id, ', ')) new_id , id, price
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) row_num
     FROM my_ids_table)
SELECT id, price
     , new_id
     , (price / COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY row_num)) :: DECIMAL (10, 2) new_price
FROM cte
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=92a74363edcdc524ddf342b53974010d

Comment: Awesome, duuude!! Thanks a lot, @Rahul Biswas.
Thank you all that tried to help as well. =D

Comment: @eduardosteps welcome.

Comment: Rahul Biswas, I tried to reproduce in a huge dataset, which I'm working on, and I figure out that this solution is only working to this specific example I posted. Could you please help me with this example using more rows? Check this out: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8cb968ac583a85ba07e208c5ac5c01ee

Line 9, for instance, we have a price of 468. It should be divided by the count of strings in id (which is 2), so the new_price for this line should be 468 / 2 = 234

Comment: hi @eduardosteps My answer will work based on your given data set where comma separated string is unique. But you've checked it with different data set where same string shows multiple times with different values. It would be better if you provide actual data set then wrote specific data set wise query.

Comment: @eduardosteps please check my result and let me know if any query regard this. Though It was accepted answer as per given image. Please check my latest query and if this helps you then mark it as accepted along with upvote so that others can pick it without any doubt when needed.

Comment: Rahul Biswas, thank you so much!! Now it is scalable and working fine for any dataset. I appreciate your kindness in sending me another solution for any case. Take care =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regexp_split_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```
select *
from my_ids_table t cross join lateral
    regexp_split_to_table(t.id, ', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I read too fast writing my solution.
But for other readers using MSQL version 2016+, you can use the STRING_SPLIT-function like below

```
SELECT a.id, LTRIM(b.value), ROUND(price / COUNT(*) over(partition by a.id), 2)
FROM my_ids_table a
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(id, ',') b
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of anyone needs to convert this solution to Spark SQL, do this:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT explode(split(id, ',')) new_id, 
        id, 
        price

FROM my_ids_table
)
  
SELECT id, 
       price,
       new_id,
       ROUND(price / size(split(id, ',')), 2) AS new_price
FROM cte
```